# string formatting inside a dict?

Tags: python, string, variables, dictionary

How do i string format inside a dict...
I tried a few things already...to no avail
I have this dict.

```
          PUTVARIABLE = sys.argv[0]

          {"payload":"http://somewonderfulsite.com/logeventType=pushSceneToChannel& \
          networkName=endoftimes&networkEmail=me@me.com&channelName=blastoff& \
          sceneType=originalAudio&sceneUrl=%(VARIABLE HERE)s&sceneDescp=uhhuh& \
          sceneTag1=ok&sceneTag3=ko& \
          sceneTip=22&sceneTipDnom=BTC&networkAvatar=empty& \
          timestamp=current_milli_time();"} % PUTVARIABLE
```

this is a json dict... it must be in this format but, i'm trying to get a string inside

there that i enter from command line or just outside the script

what am I doing wrong or not inhaling/digesting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      {"payload":"http://somewonderfulsite.com/logeventType=pushSceneToChannel& \
      networkName=endoftimes&networkEmail=me@me.com&channelName=blastoff& \
      sceneType=originalAudio&sceneUrl=%(VARIABLE HERE)s&sceneDescp=uhhuh& \
      sceneTag1=ok&sceneTag3=ko& \
      sceneTip=22&sceneTipDnom=BTC&networkAvatar=empty& \
      timestamp=current_milli_time();" % PUTVARIABLE}
```